# How can i make my code "save against concurrent invocations" when using "NSSortConcurrent" in sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

Im trying to sort an Array of NSDates using the sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator: - method od NSArray. So far all is very well and my code works as expected.
However, seeing that i can specify options for the method to use, i went into the docs and tried to figure out what they mean.
Theres NSSortStable, of course: Objects that have the same Value should be returned in the order they existed in before the sort. Thats easy enough, i guess.
But im somewhat stumped as to what NSSortConcurrent means. This is what the docs say:

```
Specifies that the Block sort operation should be concurrent.

This option is a hint and may be ignored by the implementation under some circumstances;
the code of the Block must be safe against concurrent invocation.

Available in Mac OS X v10.6 and later.
```

So i understand that i can allow the use of multiple threads for the sorting operation? thats great. In this case, is "save against concurrent invocations" just fancy talk for "thread-safe"? And if it isnt, what does it mean? Im sorry for this rather stupid question, but im not a native english speaker. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, i figured ot out. NSSortConcurrent will indeed allow the sorting operation to use multiple threads, and thus the only rewuirement is for the sorting block to be thread-safe. As long as youre not touching any data that is located outside the block (so dont use __block-variables) you should be fine.

Comment: Even though this thread is pretty old: This is not entirely true. A block isn't thread safe just because it doesn't access anything outside of it. The objects itself need to be thread save as well in that case and you need to make sure that nothing could happen on another thread that would make you compare result in a different outcome.